# what is the file format when I run h2o.save_model to save model?

Tags: h2o

In H2O when I run `h2o.save_model`, it is easy to save model. But the file do not have extension. So what is the format of the file?

I have read the http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/productionizing.html#about-pojo-mojo but it seem not belong to either POJO or MOJO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

h2o.saveModel() stores a binary H2O-3 specific model format suited for reading back with h2o.loadModel().

Note that H2O-3 binary models can only be read back with the same version of H2O that they were created with.  As a result, MOJOs have an easier-to-use backward compatibility contract and there are definitely situations where one would prefer MOJOs.